# Get index of sorted matrix

Tags: java

Suppose i enter a matrix and sort her rows, for example:

(3 5 1 4

4 3 7 2

1 0 9 7)

then sort the matrix :

(1 3 4 5

2 3 4 7

0 1 7 9)

i want show the index matrix after sorting the matrix

(2 0 3 1

3 1 0 2

1 0 3 2)

i use this code to sort the mattrix :

```
public static void sortRows(int[][] matrix){        
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {            
        Arrays.sort(matrix[i]);
     }
}
```

The problem is: how can I find the maatrix of newIndex from the input matrix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, and the answer is, you get the matrix of original indices by writing your own sorting code, which actually sorts _two_ matrices.  It sorts the first one of value, and every time something shifts, it also moves the index value in the second matrix.

Comment: how i can do it

Comment: You can do it by trying! Try and if you got stuck search for clues in the internet. You will not get your homework in Internet!

Comment: can you give me the code in java

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems Read this please.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a homework service.

Comment: i did an atempt but doesn't work

Comment: int [] sort(int mat[]){


        int temp;


        String seq = "";


   for (int i = 1; i < mat.length; i++) {


    for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {


     if (mat[j] < mat [j - 1]) {


      temp = mat[j];


      mat[j] = mat[j - 1];

      mat[j - 1] = temp;

      seq = seq + String.valueOf(j-1);



     }
     

    }


   }


      System.out.println(seq);


   return mat;


    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mat=new Element[3][4];
        int[][] gMat={{3 ,5 ,1 ,4},
                      {4 ,3 ,7 ,2},
                      {1 ,0 ,9 ,7}};
        for (int i=0;i<gMat.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<gMat[0].length;j++){
                mat[i][j]=new Element(j,gMat[i][j]);
            }
        }

        sort();
        for (int i=0;i<gMat.length;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<gMat[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(mat[i][j].idx+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static class Element{
        int idx;
        int val;
        Element(int idx,int val){
            this.idx=idx;
            this.val=val;
        }
    }

    static Element[][] mat;
    static void sort(){
        for (int i=0;i<mat.length;i++){
            Arrays.sort(mat[i], Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.val));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class MatrixEntry that holds the value and the initial index.
Implement the Comparable interface and define the method compareTo in class MatrixEntrySort.

```
class MatrixEntry {
  int value;
  int index;
}

class MatrixEntrySort implements Comparable<MatrixEntry> {

  public compareTo(MatrixEntry a, MatrixEntry b) {
    return(a.value - b.value); 
}
```

Then you can sort your Matrix this way:

```
public static void sortRows(MatrixEntry[][] matrix) { 
  MatrixEntrySort mes = new MatrixEntrySort();

  for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {            
      Arrays.sort(matrix[i], mes);
  }
}
```